# Why do we have closures in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

Am wrapping my head around JavaScript closures and am at a point where things are falling in place; i.e
a closure is the local variables for a function - kept alive after the function has returned, or
a closure is a stack-frame which is not deallocated when the function returns.

Am starting to understand this concept, but the more i understand the more i keep on wondering  why do we have to use them.

An example like this one makes me understand the concept but leaves me asking, there is a simpler way of doing this!

```
function sayHello(name) {
   var text = 'Hello ' + name;
   var sayAlert = function() { alert(text); }
   sayAlert();
}
sayHello('Gath');
```

Am just wondering why do i have to keep local variable alive? after the function has exited?

Where can i get examples showing of solutions implemented by closure and that nothing else would have worked but closures?

Comment: Look here for a great batch of answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-does-a-javascript-closure-work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closures add expressive power to the language. There are some patterns that can be implemented very easily because of closures. A few examples that come to mind include:

- [The Module Pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) - Example by Eric Miraglia
- [Memoization](http://ajaxian.com/archives/one-line-javascript-memoization) - Example by Oliver Steele
- [Currying](http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-curry/) - Example by Dustin Diaz

Answer (score 4):

"A closure is a poor man's object. An object is a poor man's closure." (Sorry, I forgot the source).

Sometimes we need variables that are needed only by *one* block of code. We put that block of code in a function and have those variables as local variables to that function.

Sometimes we need variables that are needed by *all* the functions/blocks-of-code in program. We can have these variables as global variables.

Sometimes we need variables that are needed by *some* functions/blocks-of-code. For example we have an entity called Sales and we want to put all our sales related code together. So we have a group of functions and a group of variables that deals with sales. We can put these functions and variables together in an object, so that they are isolated (both the functions and variables) from other parts of code.

In languages that don't support objects directly, we can have nested functions. The outer function acts like class, the inner functions acts like methods. Local variables to the outer function acts like fields, they are accessible only to the inner functions. In subsequent calls to inner functions, we want to maintain the state of the local-to-outer-function variables, this is where closures are needed. All that we have to do is pass reference to any inner function via output of the outer function, to code outside the outer function, so that the variables of outer function accessed by inner function are preserved even after the outer function exits.

Comment: I think I like this, but the last paragraph makes my head spin... Could you add some code to explain these analogies?

Answer (score 2):

A closure is a function with all the environnement needed for it to be executed.
In javascript, it's when an anonymous function (= lambda) is created, using a variable from an outer scope.

You can better understand why with a code like that:

```
function foo()
{
  var text = computeFromOutside();
  // ... other lines of code
  return function(otherText) { return text + otherText; }
}

bar = foo();

function baz(fun)
{
  return fun("some text");
}
```

Here, you are returning a function that uses the local variable "text".
Therefore, you are leaving the foo function scope, destroying its variables.
However, since we have an anonymous function using text, we must keep a track of this variable.
This can be achieved by value or by reference, depending on the language (Keeping the variable alive (with the possibility to modify it afterwards, or copying its value when the function is created)).

I hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

The example you chose appears on [this page](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html), so I assume you took it from there. Have you looked at all the other examples it provides? They explain the motivations for closures better than I possibly could.

Comment: Yes i did, but still they don't showcase a scenario where everything else failed and closure was the only thing that could do the trick

Comment: @gath - yes they do. Many of those examples are functions that have other functions as their return value. If you call the outer function, save a reference to the returned function, and then call the returned function at some later point, those examples couldn't possibly work without closures.

Comment: @gath: Everything can be written in assembler. Closures were not invented to solve problems that could never be solved before, so you won't find any problems that can only be solved with closures. They make certain problems much simpler to solve, and if you revisit those examples with this in mind, they might start to make more sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

A normal function does its thing, computes a result and returns it. By returning a closure, you can package off your work part-way through, and let callers get more when they are ready for it. Since I tried [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)) at university, I've been hankering for closures in every language I've worked with since... they're dangerously habit-forming!

They are also arguably an important part of the future: along with other functional programming mechanism that seem a good fit for parallel programming of multi-core systems.